# R: How to source variable files on each parallel cluster node?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to run the following code:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
requires <- c("fUnitRoots","fGarch")

for(req in requires) {
  clusterEvalQ(cl,require(req))
}

list1 <- clusterApply(cl,1:10,function(i) {
  x <- rnorm(100)
  y <- rnorm(100)
  m <- lm(y~x)
  res <- resid(m)
  t <- adfTest(res) ## this function is in {fUnitRoots}
  return(t@test$statistic)
})

stopCluster(cl)
```

However, `fUnitRoots` package is not loaded in any node. It is probably because `clusterEvalQ(cl,expr)` where `expr` is an `expression`. `require(req)` is treated as an expression where `req` is not regarded as the iterator variable as a character.

How should I refine the code to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "character.only" option is useful when calling "require" in this situation. Also, I would use "clusterCall" instead of "clusterEvalQ" to allow the package names to be passed as an argument to a worker function:

```
clusterCall(cl, function(pkgs) {
  for (req in pkgs) {
    require(req, character.only=TRUE)
  }
}, c("fUnitRoots","fGarch"))
```

This is also a bit more efficient since it loads all of the packages in a single cluster operation.

You can verify that the packages were correctly loaded using:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, search())
```

Comment: I tried your `clusterCall` code but it all returns `FALSE` for me. May you please offer some help as I need to load a large amount of library into each cluster node? Also, how do we remove some packages from every cluster nodes? I also wonder if `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(dplyr))` helps put the `library(dplyr) into each cluster node, as that was the only option working for me (and I tried `clusterExport(cl, library(dplyr))` and `clusterCall(cl, library(dplyr)`...All I got were messages `object: forcats not found`)